# Box is expected to be delivered by/in/on Q1 of 2016

Tags: grammar

- Box is expected to be delivered by Q1 of 2016
- Box is expected to be delivered in Q1 of 2016
- Box is expected to be delivered on Q1 of 2016

Answer (score 1):

"**by**" implies "*before*" with the maximum possible end date of Q1 (start).
"**in**" would suggest *anytime within Q1*, from Q1 start to Q1 end.
"**on**" would be *on the exact day* of Q1 (start).